# Downloading more files from URLs paralell

Tags: c#, multithreading, download

In a datagrindview row i have got lots of URLs.

I want download thew files from this urls

At now i use this code.:

```
int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;


            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {

                string filename = patch;

                WebClient webc = new WebClient();
                webc.DownloadFile(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), patch + "\\" + "alap" + (i+1).ToString() + ".mp4");


            }
```

And this is working for my, its download the files one by one.

I would like download files paralell (Multithread), for example 5 files download in same time.

Comment: Use google to search for  `Parallel.For`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
        int rowcount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>()
        for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
        {
           string filename = patch;
           var tsk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
                  try
                  {
                       var integerString = (i+1).ToString();
                       WebClient webc = new WebClient();
                       webc.DownloadFile(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), patch + "\\" + "alap" + integeString + ".mp4");
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                     //log
                  }
           });
           tasks.add(tsk);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Comment: How does this download multiple files concurrently? Don't you have to put it in a loop? How will you prevent it from scheduling too many downloads concurrently? This is at best an incomplete answer. More like a hint. Add some detail to make it useful.

Comment: @JimMischel I presumed that the user knew to put this code inside their already existing loop.

Comment: Hello. No, I'm sorry, but i don't know. I put your code inside the "for" loop, but i got an error message. (Unhandled device)

Comment: Sounds like a serial port problem. Are you writing these Mp4 files straight to a device? I would imagine that your device will only allow you to write one file at a time possibly?

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code" This is the exact message...

Comment: Yes. I'm downloading this MP4 files direct to my winchester. D:\alap\ folder.

Comment: see my edit. My guess would be that you didn't wait the download of the file so the program ended before the tasks had finished. Hopefully my edit has provided more information and should hopefully work

Comment: In this line.: "Task.WaitAll(tasks);" i got an error message.: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(params System.Threading.Tasks.Task[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: See edit. I forgot to convert the list to an array. Try that, it should now work

Comment: Thank you your helping. This is working, but downloaded only 3 pieces mp4 files (totaly random) and after end working. In this datagrindview row i have got 18 URLs.

Comment: I would add breakpoints to you code. See how many times your code iterates that for loop etc. try to find where the error lies

Comment: I found the problem. The program want save the mp4 file all the time alap17.mp4 name. But this is exist. I don't know why, because the name of the file should be alap1.mp4 , alap2.mp4, alap3.mp4 and soo on...

Comment: see my edit. I think the edit will work. It is to do with when the task comes to save the file the value of `i` has changed. in this case when the file downloads `i` is already the max number it can be, in this case 17. try my edit

Comment: I tried it. I got the same result like before. All the time try save alap17.mp4

Comment: I found the problem. If i tried your last edited version i got the same result like before. BUT... When i moved "int integer = i;" from try {}, and put under the "for" loop, its working perfectly.

Comment: Only one question more.... Know you how can i maximal the thread? For example i want download 5 files in one time paralell...

Comment: Because at now the program try download all 17 files in one time, and i got error, time-out.

Comment: The timeout is probably because you cycle through 17 files and try to download them. But as your computer only has say 8 cores it can only download 8 at a time. You will have to edit your timeout values on your `WebClient`. Please mark this answer as correct if it is the correct answer